# How to cooperate boost.log and ostream?

Tags: ostream, boost-log

I am using boost.log as my logging components.

It is really wonderful!

But boost.log has a lot of header to be included before working.
So I encapsulate boost.log.

Here the problem comes.
We define a class.

```
class Point2D
{ 
public: 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& strm, Point2D const& p);
private:
    double _x; double _y;
};
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& strm, Point2D const& p){
    strm<<"("<<_x<<", "<<_y<<")";
    return strm;
}
```

Before encapsulating, following code works.

```
Point2D p;
BOOST_LOG_SEV(normal)<<p;
```

After encapsulating,

```
// ------------ Log.h ----------
class Log 
{
public:
    static Log& instance();
    Log& operator<<(const char* str);
};
#define MY_LOG() Log::instance()

// ------------ Log.cpp ----------
BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(my_logger, src::logger_mt)
Log& Log::operator<<(const char* str){
    BOOST_LOG(my_logger)<<p;
}

// ------------ use.cpp -----------
Point2D p;
MY_LOG()<<p;  // !!! don't work, because "operator<<(std::ostream&, Point2D)" cannot be used directly by class Log.
```

Could anyone give me a hint to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator<<` overload for `Point2D` operates on `std::ostream` or a derived stream class, and your `Log` class is not a stream (i.e. it does not derive from `std::ostream`).

You need to

- write an `operator<<` overload that takes a reference to `Log` as the first argument, or
- make `Log` a stream by deriving it from `std::ostream` and overriding the necessary virtual member functions, or
- modify `MY_LOG` so that it returns a reference to `std::ostream` instead of `Log`.

Additionally, regardless of the way you choose, you should know that your `MY_LOG` and `Log::operator<<`, as they are designed now, will generate a log record *per every `operator<<`* call, not one record for the whole streaming expression. This is probably not what you want, so you need to design your `Log` API in such a way that it provides explicit members that begin and end a log record, so that all `operator<<` calls belonging to a record are done in between these two calls. You can see how this is done in [Boost.Log](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/ca227bc2f30d65f14719a674247728647caa2b2f/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp#L562).